# Creating a Hub like a Pivot on WP 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

What I'm trying to do was extremely easy in SL/WP 8 but seems to be impossible in WP 8.1 without redefining the Hub template myself. I want to create a hub with a header that:

1. Scrolls horizontally.
2. Has a background that scrolls along with it.
3. Has no margins on either side.

I know this can probably be solved by just having my background image include the background and the hub just being transparent, but I wanted to know if there was a way to solve it in XAML.

Putting a `Grid` with a background into the `Hub`'s header just highlights the background as much as the hub needs--not stretching all the way across:

```
<Hub>
    <Hub.Header>
        <Grid Background="Red" Height="60">
            <TextBlock Text="My Header" />
        </Grid>
    </Hub.Header>
</Hub>
```

The above makes the header with the text "My Header" but only the text part has a background. Furthermore, the `Hub` itself seems to have inner margins of 16 on each side so the background doesn't stretch across the whole phone screen.

Should I just be going with a background or deconstructing the template to remove the margins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far from an elegant solution but basically I put the background outside the Hub and gave it negative margins like so. Hacky but I guess it works.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- This is the header bar -->
    <Grid Height="64" Background="Red" />
    <Hub>
        <Hub.Header>
            <StackPanel Margin="-6,0,0,0">
                ...
            </StackPanel>
        </Hub.Header>

        <!-- actually just defined the margin in my ResourceDictionary to target all HubSections -->
        <HubSection Header="section 1" Margin="-2,-20,-4,8" />
        <HubSection Header="section 2" Margin="-2,-20,-4,8" />
    </Hub>
</Grid>
```